# Kali Linux Crashes During ibus Upgrade

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade, ibus

When upgrading Kali Linux it crashes with:

> "Oh no! Something has gone wrong."

When rebooting, the same error appears and I am not able to use the Kali OS anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this was an incompatible ibus package.
To fix this issue I had to set ibus on hold, upgrade the OS, reboot and then install the ibus upgrade:

```
apt-mark hold ibus
apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt dist-upgrade -y
reboot
apt-mark unhold ibus
apt upgrade -y
```

The debugging procedure might also be useful for other incompatible packages which crash the OS.

I restored to a previous snapshot, did the broken upgrade again and filmed it to see which package crashed it (I was too lazy to investigate the log files of the broken OS). Then I restored the snapshot again, marked the corresponding package (ibus) with *apt-mark hold* and tried to upgrade again.